# Adding GUID field with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, .net, fields-attributes, schema-architecture

I'm trying to add a GUID field programmatically to an existing FeatureClass using ArcObjects.

Here is my code:

```
ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)ipFC;

try
{
    // A try block is necessary, as an exclusive lock may not be available.
    schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);

    //Ajout d'un champ GUID
    IFieldsEdit pNewFieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)ipFC.Fields;
    IField guidField = new FieldClass();
    IFieldEdit guidFieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)guidField;
    guidFieldEdit.Name_2 = "OldGlobalID";
    guidFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGUID;
    guidFieldEdit.DefaultValue_2 = null;
    guidFieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;

    pNewFieldsEdit.AddField(guidField);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    // Handle this in a way appropriate to your application.
Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
finally
{
    // Set the lock to shared, whether or not an error occurred.
    schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
}
```

Everything seems to work (no error) and it's based on an [documentation example](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/ce43d00c-daaf-4c38-b608-2c6f411e81c1.htm#Adding). Unfortunately, when I click on the feature class in ArcCatalog and open the table preview, I have this message showing:

[image]

Also, the table open in the preview, but it's all empty (header and row) with 308 records(the correct number of row in the feature class). What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If I check the properties of my feature class, the new field seems to be there:

[image]

But the preview looks like this right after the error message...:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

I discovered that when I restart ArcCatalog and go back in the properties, the new field is gone and there is no problem opening the table preview, but the new field is nowhere to be found. Maybe there is a function to "Save" everything after the field has been added?

Comment: Are you getting a result from the `AddField` method when you perform it? For example, `FDO_E_NO_SCHEMA_LICENSE` can be returned on failure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, no error is caught during the whole process (you can see I have a try catch) and the AddField method returns 'void' in .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the [documentation example](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/ce43d00c-daaf-4c38-b608-2c6f411e81c1.htm#Adding), you'll notice that they use the IFeatureClass::AddField function

```
IField guidField = new FieldClass();
IFieldEdit guidFieldEdit = (IFieldEdit)guidField;
guidFieldEdit.Name_2 = "OldGlobalID";
guidFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGUID;
guidFieldEdit.DefaultValue_2 = null;
guidFieldEdit.IsNullable_2 = true;
ipFC.AddField(guidField);
```

In your case, you were using the feature class Fields collection to add you field (IFieldsEdit.AddField method). Which is not supported, see the Remarks section in [this article](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000369000000).

> **Remarks**
>
> AddField is used when creating a fields collection and cannot be used to insert a field into a fields collection belonging to an existing table. To add a field to an existing object class, use the IClass::AddField method.